string field size limit in InfluxDB v2
In the documentation for InfluxDB v1 I found the maximum size of strings to be 64 KB. I cannot find any documentation on that for v2 whatsoever, but by my own testing the limit seems to be 1 MB. Since I cannot find any documentation on this:

Is this 1 MB limit correct?
Is this just a default and is there a way to increase it? I have JSON data points that are larger than that. I could split them, but would like to avoid that overhead.


Yes, it says string size limit is 64 KB officially as per v2 documentation: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/reference/syntax/line-protocol/#string

Ah, missed that. Thanks. Any idea why I am observing a 1 MB limit instead, though?

could be an unofficial cap, not entirely sure though
